# No puedo encontrar el pop up con Selenium [Python 3.7]

Tags: python, selenium

estoy creando un bot para Instagram, pero luego de iniciar sesión aparece un pop up como se muestra en la siguiente captura:

[image: Pop up de instagram]

Estoy intentando encontrar el complemento con selenium indicando el xpath, sin embargo este lo logra encontrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que llevo de momento, espero me puedan ayudar:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import  Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import  By
from selenium.webdriver.support import  expected_conditions as ec

class instabot_main(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gohanckz\Desktop\Bot_instagram\geckodriver.exe")

def test_login_firefox(self):
    firefox_driver = self.driver
    firefox_driver.get("https://www.inatagram.com/")

    try:
        user = WebDriverWait(firefox_driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input")))
        user.send_keys("<usuario>")

        password = WebDriverWait(firefox_driver,5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input")))
        password.send_keys("<password>")
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    finally:
        print("Pasamos el login")

def test_cerrar_popup(self):
    firefox_driver = self.driver
    try:
        close_pop = firefox_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
        close_pop.click()
    finally:
        print("Cerramos el pop")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: A mi me ocurre el mismo error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' Para el Popup, se necesita un .click(), y no un .send_keys(Keys.ENTER) como al introducir la password, pero no consigo hacer que clicke en el objeto, donde pone "Ahora no", del popup.

Comment: De igual forma, al cambiar por : .click(). el problema se encuentra en que no me encuentra el xpath correspondiente al pop up.

Comment: @Gohanckz Si puedes ayudarme en conseguir el xpath que necesito..., he expresado una pregunta con el problema que me sucede.

Answer (score 0):

El popup no aparece inmediatamente, hay que esperar a que cargue de otro modo dicho XPATH no existe todavía.

```
def test_cerrar_popup(self):
    firefox_driver = self.driver
    try:
        WebDriverWait(firefox_driver,15).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))
        close_pop = firefox_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
        close_pop.click()
    finally:
        print("Cerramos el pop")
```